# session id coming as null in tomcat using spring SecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat

I am trying to get the session id using spring SecurityContextHolder. like below

```
public static String getSessionId(){  
        String id = null;  
        SecurityContext secContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();  
        Authentication auth = secContext.getAuthentication();  
        if(auth!=null){  
            WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();  
            if(details!=null){  
                id = details.getSessionId();  
            }  

        }  
return id;  
}
```

most of the times  `details.getSessionId();` is coming as null. sometimes it will return sessionId.  I want to know what could have caused this. is it the right way of accessing sessionId?
I tried   `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();`
this returns session id properly everytime. i want to know the difference between these two way of accessing session id.

Comment: is it the right way of accessing sessionId? probably not. You don't need spring security api for that, but servlet api: `request.getSession().getId()`

Comment: what about RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId(); to access the session id?  as i am not having access to request object in the class,  I am trying to get session id.

Answer (score 2):

You shall **not** use `auth.getDetails().getSessionId()` to get current session. It is not intended for that usage. The java doc for `WebAuthenticationDetail` says :

*String     getSessionId() : Indicates the HttpSession id the authentication request **was received from**.* (emphasize mine)

and for the creator :

```
public WebAuthenticationDetails(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)
Records the remote address and will also set the session Id if a session already exists
  (it won't create one).
Parameters:
    request - that the authentication request was received from
```

So you get the id of the session that existed when credentials were received

Worse, if you are using a `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy`, the id you get should be the one from the now invalidated session that was closed to protect against session fixation attacks.

So the correct way is to use the `RequestContextHolder` :

```
sessionId = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
```

Comment: I understood the problem, then what is the best way to ge the session id ? is it     RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();

Comment: Pay attention that RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId() forces session creation if no session exists at the moment of call. Mover overm currentRequestAttributes may produce RuntimeException.

In my point of view, it is better to use the following code to obtain sessionId:
        
ServletRequestAttributes ra = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = ra != null ? ra.getRequest().getSession(false) : null;
String sessionId = session != null ? session.getId : null;

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention that **RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()** forces session creation if no session exists at the moment of call. Moreover, **RequestContextHolder#currentRequestAttributes()** may produce RuntimeException.

In my point of view, for logging purposes it is better and more safe to use the following code to obtain sessionId:

```
ServletRequestAttributes ra = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = ra != null ? ra.getRequest().getSession(false) : null;
String sessionId = session != null ? session.getId : null;
```